# C# getelment by classname

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I'm trying to get an element by class name from a table in IE(internet explorer). i have tried something like this:

```
foreach (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie in shellWindows) {
   string wqmURL = "https://wqm-eme.accenture.com/arsys/forms/wqmeme";
   if (ie.LocationURL.StartsWith(wqmURL)) {
      var doc = ie.Document;  
      var testText = doc.getElementByClassName("");
      testText.click();
   }
   ie.BeforeNavigate2 += new
   SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_BeforeNavigate2EventHandler(this.ie_BeforeNavigate2);
}
```

But this isn't work and i don't know any other way to select an element from a table in Internet explorer.Let's say I wana get the "In Progress" element. Here is the html code :

```
<div class="MenuOuter" style="left: 602px; top: 240px; width: 161px; height: 0px; visibility: hidden; z-index: 100003;" armenuelementserial="0">
<iframe src="https://wqm-eme.accenture.com/arsys/resources/html/Blank.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; position: absolute;"></iframe>
<div class="MenuTableContainer">
<table class="MenuTable" style="width: 159px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody class="MenuTableBody">
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
    <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">New</td>
    <td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="New"></td></tr>
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
    <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">Assigned</td>
    <td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="Assigned"></td></tr>
<tr class="MenuTableRow">
    <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">In Progress</td>
    <td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="In Progress"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: You didn't specify the class name.

Comment: I said above i wana select te cass name witch is assigned to value "Assigned"                                                                                                <tr class="MenuTableRow">
    <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">Assigned</td>
    <td class="MenuEntryNoSub" arvalue="Assigned"></td></tr>
or for In progress it's doesn't matter i just need to know how to select one of them

Comment: No, I meant you literally didn't specify the class name: `var testText = doc.getElementByClassName("CLASS NAME HERE");`

Comment: that was the exemple that have i tried,

it was like this var testText = doc.getElementByClassName("MenuEntryName"); I belive i need in the first step to select the div in witch the table is created, but i also failed to select it.

Comment: Hmm, you shouldn't need to get the parent... However are you sure that the `GetElementByClassName()` method exists? Due to that you use the `var` keyword you might cause it to use late-binding. Late-binding is when you try to access members of an object that you are not currently certain that they exist. This happens with dynamic objects.

Comment: Also, usually you are getting an _array of elements_ when getting by class name (using the `GetElementsByClassName()` method - take note of the _'s'_ in _Elements_). This is because classes tend to be applied to multiple elements, and not just one. -- However I cannot find either [**in the documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752541(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: you were right about the 's' in the doc.getElementsByClassName("MenuEntryName"); it's reading the var statement without any error, but now the error it's at testText.click(); The error it's says the following: "Additional information: 'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'click' ".

Comment: I'm not in to using only this method, I'm opened to use any other method, but the problem it's i don't know any other. If you can share with me it will kindly be appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: Like I said, it's an array: `testText[0].click();`

Comment: it doesn't work..

Comment: Hmm, must be a custom collection then. I'll test it in a moment.

Comment: Any errors? It works for me.

Comment: i don't get any error but it's also not doing what it was supposed to do

Comment: I don't quite understand how you want to "select" a table cell. It is not selectable. What is it supposed to do, by the way?

Comment: For exemple, let's just say there is a web-site from you wanna buy something, I was trying to build that WindowsFormApplication to see if I can replicate human activity(by that I mean pressing a radio box select some value from a dropdownlist, write something on a label box and thing's like this). And I've met the problem above, but if you say i can't select a value from a table that is not selectable i understand.
Anyway thank yuo for trying to help me. Have a nice day!

Comment: A _table_ or its contents cannot be selected. You must select the individual radio button/drop down item. You're trying to select a table cell. A table is only for displaying data, not interacting with it. Could you give me the link to the website?

Comment: The website it is (https://wqm-eme.accenture.com/arsys/forms/wqmeme) 
but you won't have access to it. the only thing i can do it's to make you print-screen to the web site and to it's code

Comment: if you can provide me with an email adress i will make all the print-screen that I think it will be necessary to know and send it to you.

Comment: Just take a screenshot of what you want to select and its code, then upload it to http://imgur.com/ and link it in the comments. Also note that your code must be executed when the document has finished loading.

Comment: Or if you need any other part of the HTML/javascript code tell me and i'll post it

Comment: You didn't post anything.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/MsJMkkW.png here it's the link

Comment: Hmm, that website must be designed in a very special way. Without access to it there isn't much I can do then... The best advice I can give you is to inspect its code and scripts and look for references to the drop down.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that you could try to click the drop down itself at first, so that it is opened, then click the item you want to select.

Comment: I succeded in click on the dropdownlist, because it's haveing an ID and it's work perfectly using this code[var clickoption = doc.getElementById("arid_WIN_2_7");and then  clickoption.click()] and it's opening, but after that I've tried to select an option from that dropdownlist but as you already know I faild...every thing i've tryed isn't working.

Comment: Anyway thank you for trying to helping me and i'm sorry if I waste your time. Have a nice day! :)

Comment: You didn't waste my time, I practically volunteered to help you. Not every attempt to help is a success ;). You have a nice day as well!